# Call Class Methods from inflated View

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Quick Question. I wrote some View Classes and included them in a Fragment via XML.These View Classes are getting inflated.

```
private void inflateView(Context context){
    inflater =(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_motoreffiziens_view, this, true);
}
```

In the onCreateView of the my fragment I get the View reference by findViewById.
To fullfill some task i implemented a listener for my View which I can add with my intern method addListeners(myCustomListener).

My Problem is now that I cant call methods (because its obviously a View and not a ClassReference).

My View Header

```
public class MotorSelection  extends RelativeLayout implements Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener {

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private SpinnerChange spinnerChangeListener = null ;
```

This View is nested in my Fragment XML :

```
<com.example.andy.einzelprojekt1.views.MotorSelection
    android:id="@+id/view_motor_selection"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

So my Question is how I can use my Methods from inflated Views?
More specific:

In the onCreate of my Fragment I want to acess this view and add a listener.

Greetings

/e 20.5.16

Comment: I think you just need to cast your view to your class which extends View, but you should provide more code to be sure and to better help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please post code of your `View` class?
Actually, inflated view is instance of your class, so you should be able to call `view.yourMethod()`.

Another way (if I am missing something in your question), is to use `Reflection`.
For example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896315/android-java-calling-a-method-using-reflection).

Comment: yeah. I thought that as well but the methods are not aceessbile.

Answer (score 0):

Okay stupid mistake. 
I castet my View to the extended Object (in my Case RelativeLayout). Because of that I couldnt access my methods declared in the new ViewClass.

```
motorselection = (MotorSelection) rootView.findViewById(R.id.view_motor_selection);
```

/answered