# Android studio cannot find the symbol defined in '.jar' file

Tags: android, jar, android-source

I use `Context.COUNTRY_DETECTOR` in my android studio project, it's a hide symbol in android source code, so I add the *framework.jar* into libs:
[framework.jar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4NZn.png)

Module dependencies setting:
[dependencies setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vr5Bj.png)
but it reports cannot resolve symbol error when I click the 'run app' button.

Answer (score 1):

In order to call hidden methods you need to [create your own custom SDK](https://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/) and replace it with the one you use to import all android related methods (you can also use [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4896334/6028746)).

My recommendation to you specific case is just use the string value of the constant:

```
String COUNTRY_DETECTOR = "country_detector"
```