# Reflection in Android?

Tags: java, android

I'm little bit stuck on my current Android app project, the thing is that i have 84 variable on my AppPreference Class, now I'm required to get all those variables at one, to create packages and send the over bluetooth, i was thinking that maybe Reflections would help me do it, here is what I'm trying to do:

1.- Build a String out of my i and j variables:

```
for(int i=1;i <= 7;i++){
            for(int j = 1;j <=4;j++){

                String func ="getD"+i+"t"+j+"h";

  }
}
```

2.- My functions are the following:

```
    public class AppPreferences {

    public static final String NOZZ = "nozzles";
    public static final String TANK = "tank";
    public static final String SYNC ="sync";

    //Day 1
    public static final String D1T1H = "d1t1h";
    public static final String D1T1M = "d1t1m";
    public static final String D1T1RT = "d1t1rt";

    public static final String D1T2H = "d1t2h";
    public static final String D1T2M = "d1t2m";
    public static final String D1T2RT = "d1t2rt";

    public static final String D1T3H = "d1t3h";
    public static final String D1T3M = "d1t3m";
    public static final String D1T3RT = "d1t3rt";

    public static final String D1T4H = "d1t4h";
    public static final String D1T4M = "d1t4m";
    public static final String D1T4RT = "d1t4rt";

    //Day 2
    public static final String D2T1H = "d2t1h";
    public static final String D2T1M = "d2t1m";
    public static final String D2T1RT = "d2t1rt";

    public static final String D2T2H = "d2t2h";
    public static final String D2T2M = "d2t2m";
    public static final String D2T2RT = "d2t2rt";

    public static final String D2T3H = "d2t3h";
    public static final String D2T3M = "d2t3m";
    public static final String D2T3RT = "d2t3rt";

    public static final String D2T4H = "d2t4h";
    public static final String D2T4M = "d2t4m";
    public static final String D2T4RT = "d2t4rt";

    //Day 3
    public static final String D3T1H = "d3t1h";
    public static final String D3T1M = "d3t1m";
    public static final String D3T1RT = "d3t1rt";

    public static final String D3T2H = "d3t2h";
    public static final String D3T2M = "d3t2m";
    public static final String D3T2RT = "d3t2rt";

    public static final String D3T3H = "d3t3h";
    public static final String D3T3M = "d3t3m";
    public static final String D3T3RT = "d3t3rt";

    public static final String D3T4H = "d3t4h";
    public static final String D3T4M = "d3t4m";
    public static final String D3T4RT = "d3t4rt";

    //Day 4
    public static final String D4T1H = "d4t1h";
    public static final String D4T1M = "d4t1m";
    public static final String D4T1RT = "d4t1rt";

    public static final String D4T2H = "d4t2h";
    public static final String D4T2M = "d4t2m";
    public static final String D4T2RT = "d4t2rt";

    public static final String D4T3H = "d4t3h";
    public static final String D4T3M = "d4t3m";
    public static final String D4T3RT = "d4t3rt";

    public static final String D4T4H = "d4t4h";
    public static final String D4T4M = "d4t4m";
    public static final String D4T4RT = "d4t4rt";

    //Day 5
    public static final String D5T1H = "d5t1h";
    public static final String D5T1M = "d5t1m";
    public static final String D5T1RT = "d5t1rt";

    public static final String D5T2H = "d5t2h";
    public static final String D5T2M = "d5t2m";
    public static final String D5T2RT = "d5t2rt";

    public static final String D5T3H = "d5t3h";
    public static final String D5T3M = "d5t3m";
    public static final String D5T3RT = "d5t3rt";

    public static final String D5T4H = "d5t4h";
    public static final String D5T4M = "d5t4m";
    public static final String D5T4RT = "d5t4rt";

    //Day 6
    public static final String D6T1H = "d6t1h";
    public static final String D6T1M = "d6t1m";
    public static final String D6T1RT = "d6t1rt";

    public static final String D6T2H = "d6t2h";
    public static final String D6T2M = "d6t2m";
    public static final String D6T2RT = "d6t2rt";

    public static final String D6T3H = "d6t3h";
    public static final String D6T3M = "d6t3m";
    public static final String D6T3RT = "d6t3rt";

    public static final String D6T4H = "d6t4h";
    public static final String D6T4M = "d6t4m";
    public static final String D6T4RT = "d6t4rt";

    //Day 7
    public static final String D7T1H = "d7t1h";
    public static final String D7T1M = "d7t1m";
    public static final String D7T1RT = "d7t1rt";

    public static final String D7T2H = "d7t2h";
    public static final String D7T2M = "d7t2m";
    public static final String D7T2RT = "d7t2rt";

    public static final String D7T3H = "d7t3h";
    public static final String D7T3M = "d7t3m";
    public static final String D7T3RT = "d7t3rt";

    public static final String D7T4H = "d7t4h";
    public static final String D7T4M = "d7t4m";
    public static final String D7T4RT = "d7t4rt";

    private static final String APP_SHARED_PREFS = AppPreferences.class.getSimpleName();
    private SharedPreferences _sharedPrefs;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor _prefsEditor;

    public AppPreferences(Context context){
        this._sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(APP_SHARED_PREFS, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        this._prefsEditor = _sharedPrefs.edit();
    }

    public String getSync(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(SYNC,"0");
    }

    public void setSync(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(SYNC, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getNozz(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(NOZZ,"00");
    }

    public void setNozz(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(NOZZ, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getTank(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(TANK,"00");
    }

    public void setTank(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(TANK, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    //DAY 1 T1
    public String getD1t1h(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D1T1H,"00");
    }

    public void setD1t1h(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D1T1H, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD1t1m(){ return _sharedPrefs.getString(D1T1M,"00"); }

    public void setD1t1m(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D1T1M, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD1t1rt(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D1T1RT,"00");
    }

    public void setD1t1rt(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D1T1RT, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    //DAY 1 T2
    public String getD1t2h(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D1T2H,"00");
    }

    public void setD1t2h(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D1T2H, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD1t2m(){ return _sharedPrefs.getString(D1T2M,"00"); }

    public void setD1t2m(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D1T2M, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD1t2rt(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D1T2RT,"00");
    }

    public void setD1t2rt(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D1T2RT, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    //DAY 1 T3
    public String getD1t3h(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D1T3H,"00");
    }

    public void setD1t3h(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D1T3H, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD1t3m(){ return _sharedPrefs.getString(D1T3M,"00"); }

    public void setD1t3m(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D1T3M, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD1t3rt(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D1T3RT,"00");
    }

    public void setD1t3rt(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D1T3RT, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    //DAY 1 T4
    public String getD1t4h(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D1T4H,"00");
    }

    public void setD1t4h(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D1T4H, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD1t4m(){ return _sharedPrefs.getString(D1T4M,"00"); }

    public void setD1t4m(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D1T4M, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD1t4rt(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D1T4RT,"00");
    }

    public void setD1t4rt(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D1T4RT, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    //---------------------

    //DAY 2 T1
    public String getD2t1h(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D2T1H,"00");
    }

    public void setD2t1h(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D2T1H, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD2t1m(){ return _sharedPrefs.getString(D2T1M,"00"); }

    public void setD2t1m(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D2T1M, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD2t1rt(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D2T1RT,"00");
    }

    public void setD2t1rt(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D2T1RT, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    //DAY 2 T2
    public String getD2t2h(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D2T2H,"00");
    }

    public void setD2t2h(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D2T2H, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD2t2m(){ return _sharedPrefs.getString(D2T2M,"00"); }

    public void setD2t2m(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D2T2M, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD2t2rt(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D2T2RT,"00");
    }

    public void setD2t2rt(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D2T2RT, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    //DAY 2 T3
    public String getD2t3h(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D2T3H,"00");
    }

    public void setD2t3h(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D2T3H, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD2t3m(){ return _sharedPrefs.getString(D2T3M,"00"); }

    public void setD2t3m(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D2T3M, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD2t3rt(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D2T3RT,"00");
    }

    public void setD2t3rt(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D2T3RT, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    //DAY 2 T4
    public String getD2t4h(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D2T4H,"00");
    }

    public void setD2t4h(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D2T4H, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD2t4m(){ return _sharedPrefs.getString(D2T4M,"00"); }

    public void setD2t4m(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D2T4M, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD2t4rt(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D2T4RT,"00");
    }

    public void setD2t4rt(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D2T4RT, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    //-------------------

    //DAY 3 T1
    public String getD3t1h(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D3T1H,"00");
    }

    public void setD3t1h(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D3T1H, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD3t1m(){ return _sharedPrefs.getString(D3T1M,"00"); }

    public void setD3t1m(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D3T1M, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD3t1rt(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D3T1RT,"00");
    }

    public void setD3t1rt(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D3T1RT, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    //DAY 3 T2
    public String getD3t2h(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D3T2H,"00");
    }

    public void setD3t2h(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D3T2H, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD3t2m(){ return _sharedPrefs.getString(D3T2M,"00"); }

    public void setD3t2m(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D3T2M, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD3t2rt(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D3T2RT,"00");
    }

    public void setD3t2rt(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D3T2RT, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    //DAY 3 T3
    public String getD3t3h(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D3T3H,"00");
    }

    public void setD3t3h(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D3T3H, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD3t3m(){ return _sharedPrefs.getString(D3T3M,"00"); }

    public void setD3t3m(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D3T3M, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD3t3rt(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D3T3RT,"00");
    }

    public void setD3t3rt(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D3T3RT, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    //DAY 3 T4
    public String getD3t4h(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D3T4H,"00");
    }

    public void setD3t4h(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D3T4H, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD3t4m(){ return _sharedPrefs.getString(D3T4M,"00"); }

    public void setD3t4m(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D3T4M, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD3t4rt(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D3T4RT,"00");
    }

    public void setD3t4rt(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D3T4RT, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    //-----------------------

    //DAY 4 T1
    public String getD4t1h(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D4T1H,"00");
    }

    public void setD4t1h(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D4T1H, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD4t1m(){ return _sharedPrefs.getString(D4T1M,"00"); }

    public void setD4t1m(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D4T1M, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD4t1rt(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D4T1RT,"00");
    }

    public void setD4t1rt(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D4T1RT, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    //DAY 4 T2
    public String getD4t2h(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D4T2H,"00");
    }

    public void setD4t2h(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D4T2H, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD4t2m(){ return _sharedPrefs.getString(D4T2M,"00"); }

    public void setD4t2m(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D4T2M, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD4t2rt(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D4T2RT,"00");
    }

    public void setD4t2rt(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D4T2RT, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    //DAY 4 T3
    public String getD4t3h(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D4T3H,"00");
    }

    public void setD4t3h(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D4T3H, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD4t3m(){ return _sharedPrefs.getString(D4T3M,"00"); }

    public void setD4t3m(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D4T3M, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD4t3rt(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D4T3RT,"00");
    }

    public void setD4t3rt(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D4T3RT, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    //DAY 4 T4
    public String getD4t4h(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D4T4H,"00");
    }

    public void setD4t4h(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D4T4H, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD4t4m(){ return _sharedPrefs.getString(D4T4M,"00"); }

    public void setD4t4m(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D4T4M, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD4t4rt(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D4T4RT,"00");
    }

    public void setD4t4rt(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D4T4RT, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    //-----------------------

    //DAY 5 T1
    public String getD5t1h(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D5T1H,"00");
    }

    public void setD5t1h(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D5T1H, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD5t1m(){ return _sharedPrefs.getString(D5T1M,"00"); }

    public void setD5t1m(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D5T1M, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD5t1rt(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D5T1RT,"00");
    }

    public void setD5t1rt(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D5T1RT, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    //DAY 5 T2
    public String getD5t2h(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D5T2H,"00");
    }

    public void setD5t2h(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D5T2H, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD5t2m(){ return _sharedPrefs.getString(D5T2M,"00"); }

    public void setD5t2m(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D5T2M, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD5t2rt(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D5T2RT,"00");
    }

    public void setD5t2rt(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D5T2RT, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    //DAY 5 T3
    public String getD5t3h(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D5T3H,"00");
    }

    public void setD5t3h(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D5T3H, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD5t3m(){ return _sharedPrefs.getString(D5T3M,"00"); }

    public void setD5t3m(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D5T3M, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD5t3rt(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D5T3RT,"00");
    }

    public void setD5t3rt(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D5T3RT, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    //DAY 5 T4
    public String getD5t4h(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D5T4H,"00");
    }

    public void setD5t4h(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D5T4H, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD5t4m(){ return _sharedPrefs.getString(D5T4M,"00"); }

    public void setD5t4m(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D5T4M, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD5t4rt(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D5T4RT,"00");
    }

    public void setD5t4rt(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D5T4RT, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    //-----------------------

    //DAY 6 T1
    public String getD6t1h(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D6T1H,"00");
    }

    public void setD6t1h(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D6T1H, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD6t1m(){ return _sharedPrefs.getString(D6T1M,"00"); }

    public void setD6t1m(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D6T1M, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD6t1rt(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D6T1RT,"00");
    }

    public void setD6t1rt(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D6T1RT, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    //DAY 6 T2
    public String getD6t2h(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D6T2H,"00");
    }

    public void setD6t2h(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D6T2H, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD6t2m(){ return _sharedPrefs.getString(D6T2M,"00"); }

    public void setD6t2m(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D6T2M, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD6t2rt(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D6T2RT,"00");
    }

    public void setD6t2rt(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D6T2RT, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    //DAY 6 T3
    public String getD6t3h(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D6T3H,"00");
    }

    public void setD6t3h(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D6T3H, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD6t3m(){ return _sharedPrefs.getString(D6T3M,"00"); }

    public void setD6t3m(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D6T3M, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD6t3rt(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D6T3RT,"00");
    }

    public void setD6t3rt(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D6T3RT, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    //DAY 6 T4
    public String getD6t4h(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D6T4H,"00");
    }

    public void setD6t4h(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D6T4H, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD6t4m(){ return _sharedPrefs.getString(D6T4M,"00"); }

    public void setD6t4m(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D6T4M, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD6t4rt(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D6T4RT,"00");
    }

    public void setD6t4rt(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D6T4RT, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    //-----------------------

    //DAY 7 T1
    public String getD7t1h(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D7T1H,"00");
    }

    public void setD7t1h(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D7T1H, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD7t1m(){ return _sharedPrefs.getString(D7T1M,"00"); }

    public void setD7t1m(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D7T1M, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD7t1rt(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D7T1RT,"00");
    }

    public void setD7t1rt(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D7T1RT, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    //DAY 7 T2
    public String getD7t2h(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D7T2H,"00");
    }

    public void setD7t2h(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D7T2H, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD7t2m(){ return _sharedPrefs.getString(D7T2M,"00"); }

    public void setD7t2m(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D7T2M, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD7t2rt(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D7T2RT,"00");
    }

    public void setD7t2rt(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D7T2RT, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    //DAY 7 T3
    public String getD7t3h(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D7T3H,"00");
    }

    public void setD7t3h(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D7T3H, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD7t3m(){ return _sharedPrefs.getString(D7T3M,"00"); }

    public void setD7t3m(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D7T3M, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD7t3rt(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D7T3RT,"00");
    }

    public void setD7t3rt(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D7T3RT, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    //DAY 7 T4
    public String getD7t4h(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D7T4H,"00");
    }

    public void setD7t4h(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D7T4H, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD7t4m(){ return _sharedPrefs.getString(D7T4M,"00"); }

    public void setD7t4m(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D7T4M, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    public String getD7t4rt(){
        return _sharedPrefs.getString(D7T4RT,"00");
    }

    public void setD7t4rt(String text){
        _prefsEditor.putString(D7T4RT, text);
        _prefsEditor.commit();
    }

}
```

3.- The instance of the class is called _appPreferences:

```
_appPrefs = new AppPreferences(getContext().getApplicationContext());
```

4.-I would like to do something like this:

```
public void syncData(){

        for(int i=1;i <= 7;i++){
            for(int j = 1;j <=4;j++){

                String func ="getD"+i+"t"+j+"h";
                String temp = _appPrefs.func;
            }
        }
    }
```

Is this even possible? I think its called Reflections, but i can find a good example since I'm new with reflections. Sorry for my English I'm not native english speaker. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that approach required ? Why you do not use map or list and add proper logic which will simplify things you want to do.

Comment: What's wrong with a `HashMap`?

Comment: hashmap....????

Comment: something like that http://stackoverflow.com/a/4896334/814304 ?

Comment: how would i populate the hashmap? it would require something like this too? the things is that all those values need to be saved for the user every time they open the app, the app is all about configuring an schedule to run on an Arduino.

Comment: @iMysak already look into that, but is not too clear for me, as i said it before I'm not familiar with what they are proposing there.

Comment: When I see something this tortured, I realize it must be getting done with the wrong tool.  I think what you want in this case is a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume you have:

```
  class AppPreferences {
    public void d2t3h() {
      System.out.println("helo");
    }
  }
```

Then try next code(working example, I used static nested class AppPreferences):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  AppPreferences preferences = new AppPreferences();
  for(int i=1;i <= 7;i++){
    for(int j = 1;j <=4;j++){
      try {
        String func ="getD"+i+"t"+j+"h";
        Method method = AppPreferences.class.getMethod(func);
        Object result = method.invoke(preferences);
        System.out.print(result);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.print(".");
      }
    }
}
```

I guess now you figure out how to use it next, If you want I can add more explanation here.

I you need to invoke method with parameters then you need to define them:

```
    Method method = AppPreferences.class.getMethod(func, String.class);
    Object result = method.invoke(a, "param");
```

Comment: what does "a" stands for in the method.invoke(a)? I'm really new with Reflections :C

Comment: @IñakiPedrocheAramburu a-> appPreferences , I update code with propitiate names

Comment: you are the man, thank you very much, this is the accepted answer.

Comment: @IñakiPedrocheAramburu, I am here to help ;)